# Forced Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I'm just starting my journey to QFT and Particles physics and I have a question about the problem of QHO witch we hit with a force $F(t)$ for $ t< t' $, for which the force is zero for $t>t'$.

I have found the $G_{ret}(t,t')$ and I have solved the PDE, finding

$$q(t)=q_0(t)+\frac{i}{2\omega}(\tilde{F}(\omega)e^{-i\omega t }-c.c) $$

and

$$\langle E \rangle_{t>t'}=\langle 0|\hat{H}|0 \rangle =\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega+\frac{1}{2}|\tilde{F}(\omega)|^2 . $$

I have to find the probability amplitude $(=P_n)$ to find it in a random superstate with $\langle E \rangle = \sum_{n}P_nE_n $ after t'.

The idea is that the state will be a linear combination of states of the QHO and I have to found the probability to found it a random state $n$.

I hope i made my self clear about the problem, but if not I know that the subject is not clear to me at the moment and I hope to archive it!

***How to use the solution for q(t) to find the probability for each fock state |n⟩ after the oscillator has been forced?***

Comment: I'm not seeing a *question* here - what are you asking?

Comment: I think he's asking how to use the solution he has for $q(t)$ to find the probability for each fock state $|n\rangle$ after the oscillator has been forced.

Comment: Any ideas about the problem?

Comment: Hi Nikos. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Ok I know, but this problem its not my homework but some question that I make to myself and I try to solve my self, and i stuck at this point..